# Populate shuttle based on drop down list in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a mini work in ADF in which I am required to create a form. One input in the form is continent which is a drop down list of various continent.
There is another input(shuttle) with country names. Suppose the user chooses ASIA from drop down list of continent, then the below shuttle should get populated with countries from ASIA.

How can I achieve that in ADF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a view criteria on your shuttle VO filtering by ContinentId:

[image: View Criteria on your Countries VO]

Make sure you include your bind variable accessors on your VOImpl:

[image: include your bind variable accessors on your VOImpl]

And also make sure that you apply your view criteria on your application module:

[image: apply your view criteria on your application module]

Then follow this steps:

[image: follow this steps]

That way you will finally your shuttle filtered:

[image: final result]

Comment: Thanks Juan. Will work through and let you know of my improvement. Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to filter out your countries based on Continent so for that apply a view criteria(based on Continent) on your VO (which is used by your shuttle input).